# Transform Web.config on build

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, msbuild, web-config

I have an ASP.NET application with Web.Config configured with several connection strings.

I also have a Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config which contain transforms for the strings and are applied when deploying. Which works fine.

Example of transform in the Web.Release.config:

```
<add name ="ConnectionKey" connectionString="Server=*******" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"
     xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
```

However I would like the transform to also be applied on builds so I could run a script building my application and running several tests before publishing.

I tried to add the following code in my project's file (Source : https://gist.github.com/EdCharbeneau/9135216 ):

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <!-- Transform the file out to a temp file, sourcing from our Web.config file: -->
    <TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config.temp"
                  Condition="Exists('Web.$(Configuration).config')" />

    <!-- Copy the temp file, back over the top of Web.config, the file handle opened by TransformXml is closed now: -->
    <Copy SourceFiles="Web.config.temp" DestinationFiles="Web.config"
          Condition="Exists('Web.config.temp')" />

    <!-- Cleanup after ourselves: -->
    <Delete Files="Web.config.temp" Condition="Exists('Web.config.temp')" />
  </Target>
```

But when I check the bin folder it's always the default Web.Config that is present, not the transformed one.

Comment: Is it creating the `Web.config.temp` file? What happens if you remove the `<Delete...` line? Are you sure you are building in Release mode too?

Comment: No I can't see the temp file anywhere. I've tried building in Debug/Release, the transformation is not applied in both cases.

Comment: Do you have an import for `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` in your csproj too?

Comment: I have the following line : <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />

Comment: I also tried replacing $configuration by plain Release, removing the condition, still can't see that temp file created.

Comment: Will the results change if you change to use absolute path for `SourceFiles` and `DestinationFiles`? Was the behavior of `Copy` task recorded in Output log(Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build And Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity > Detailed)?